# How to get the script reference present in hierarchy

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, unityscript

In my game hierarchy there are a lot of game object which have a script on them. I need to remove that script from each one of them. So one method is that i find each object present in scene (200- 300) and remove the script one by one. it is very time consuming.
Is there any other option or method by which I can remove the script at once from all objects.

Answer (score 0):

I found the a method . Just go to the script in assets window where your script resides -> right click on the script -> (select option from pop up window) find references. And you will have the filtered hierarchy.